# Как добавить список друзей пользователя в форму другой модели?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Модель User:

```
 has_many :shipments, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :friendships
 has_many :friends, through: :friendships
 has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => 'Friendship', 
                             :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
 has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

Модель Friendship:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
has_many   :shipments
```

Модель Shipment:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friendship
```

FriendshipsController:

```
def index
  @friendships = Friendship.all
end
```

Форма объекта shipment:

```
<%= form_for(@shipment, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Ф.И.О." %>
  <%= f.user.friendships.each do |friend| %>
    <%= friend.name %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Тем не менее выдает:

```
NoMethodError in ShipmentsController#new
undefined method `user' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f1e4ee2eac8>
```

---

Full Trace

```
app/controllers/shipments_controller.rb:35:in `user'
app/views/shipments/new.html.erb:50:in `block in _app_views_shipments_new_html_erb__629865209450934427_69883691027280'
app/views/shipments/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_shipments_new_html_erb__629865209450934427_69883691027280'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/core.rb:155:in `find'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:67:in `user'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:202:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:444:in `form_for'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Мне необходимо что бы при создании модели Shipment - заполняя форму - User мог отметить другого User:а из списка своих друзей по модели Friendship по (friend_id). Я понимаю что Rails не видит метода name, но не понимаю почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я понимаю что Rails не видит метода name, но не понимаю почему?

Вообще-то, проблема с методом `user` а не `name`.
Тут всё просто:

> ```
> <%= form_for(@shipment, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
> ```

`f`, с которым дальше идёт работа, это объект класса рельсового `FormBuilder`, но никак не пользовательского `Shipment`. Соответственно, метода (отношения) `user` у него нет.

Варианты решения:

**Первый**

Использовать привязанный к билдеру объект (это и будет `@shipment` который передали в `form_for`)

```
f.object.user.friendships.each do |friend|
# ...
end
```

**Второй**

Использовать непосредственно переменную инстанса

```
@shipment.user.friendship #...
```

**Третий**

Имхо, самый правильный с точки зрения дальнейшей работы с кодом.
Использовать `helper_methods`:

```
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :shipment, :user

  private

  def user
    @user ||= User.find(params[:user_id]) #это для примера
  end

  def shipment
    @shipment ||= user.shipments.new # тоже для примера
  end
end

# Вьюха
<%= form_for(shipment, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <% user.friendships.each do |friend| %>
    <%= friend.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**UPD:**
Пример выше основан на том коде, который был в вопросе.
Если нужен именно выбор, то будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<%= form_for(shipment, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :friendship_id, user.friendships.map{ |friendship| [friendship.friend.name, friendship.id] } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, ТСа интересует `<select>` или другой способ выбора со списком друзей, но объяснение в целом хорошее.

Comment: @D-side, из текста вопроса мне показалась что проблема в другом. Но на всякий случай добавил и про это :)

Comment: Абсолютно верно - методом будет select - но это формальность. Третий вариант выглядит отлично, но тем не менее теперь выдает: "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ShipmentsController#new Couldn't find User with 'id'=" - видимо я опять что то накосячил. Пробовал и :id и :friend_id и :user_id - результат тот же.

Comment: @lif3ar, а можно увидеть код, в котором валится? Я так подозреваю что просто опять непонятки с сущностями, для которых передаётся `id`.

Comment: Видимо да, 
"      record = s.execute([id], self, connection).first
       unless record
          raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{name} with '#{primary_key}'=#{id}"
       end
       record
    rescue RangeError
"

Comment: @lif3ar, это уже код из внутренностей рельсов. Нужен тот код из бэктрейса, который твой. Ну или весь бэктрейс.

Comment: Разобрался что такое трэйс)) Добавил код в обновление.

Comment: @lif3ar, а! Ругается на метод `user`. Видимо это ты код скопировал который я для примера давал? Вообще, тебе скорее всего нужен текущий пользователь, от имени которого всё происходит (а не искать из базы). Это тот же юзер, которого ты до этого в `@user` клал.

Comment: @anoam Да, тот вариант из примера казался логичным. С заменой на текущего пользователя - наметился конец этой эпопеи. В контроллере Shipments сделал хэлперы user: (at)user = current_user и shipment: (at)shipment = user.shipments.new . В view-файл идеально подошло <%= f.select :friendship_id, user.friendships.map{ |friendship| [friendship.friend.name, friendship.id] } %>. Сейчас разбираюсь как это в shipment/show выбранного пользователя показать. Просто ОГРОМНОЕ Вам спасибо, три дня бодался с этой фигней.